# How to install gcc 9.X on RHEL8?

Tags: rhel, gcc

I see from the documentation [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/developing_c_and_cpp_applications_in_rhel_8/gcc-toolset-9_toolsets) that `gcc` has been updated on RHEL8, but what I haven't figured out is how to get it.

[The documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/installing_managing_and_removing_user-space_components/index#distribution-of-content-in-rhel8_using-appstream) indicates that there are now two streams, but I already have both and `gcc` is still at 8.X.

If I go through `dnf` with `dnf search gcc | grep 9` there are a great deal of references to `gcc` v9, but no way to actually install it. There is something called `gcc-toolset-9`, but after checking it out, it is unrelated to the core gcc version.

Answer (score 2):

I feel foolish because I figured it out right after posting, but I figured I'd share because it isn't intuitive and hopefully this will save someone some time.

The package you want to install is *not* `gcc`. You want to install `gcc-toolset-9`. You will notice after installation that you will still get 8.x if you do a `gcc --version`. `gcc-toolset-9` installs to /opt. The idea is to give you a separate development environment. See [this documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/developing_c_and_cpp_applications_in_rhel_8/gcc-toolset_toolsets#what-is-gcc-toolset_gcc-toolset). After installation you can run the updated gcc with `/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-9/<username>/bin/gcc`.

As @Stephen Kitt pointed out, you can actually get a shell with the updated toolset by running `scl enable gcc-toolset-9 bash`. Running this command will open a new bash session with the environment variables appropriately updated.

You can also run gcc v.9 directly with `scl enable gcc-toolset-9 gcc <your_gcc_args>`. See [this documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/developing_c_and_cpp_applications_in_rhel_8/gcc-toolset_toolsets#running-a-tool-from-gcc-toolset_gcc-toolset) for details.

Comment: Better yet, run GCC with `scl enable gcc-toolset-9 gcc`, or run a shell with the appropriate environment using `scl enable gcc-toolset-9 bash`.

Comment: I'll update my answer